# Login to facebook in a as3 application

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I've been trying to get my as3 application to connect to facebook using it's SDK for flash. However most tutorials on internet talk about using php, js or flex.

Is there any way to login to facebook using only as3?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go near Adobe's swc for Facebook
Adobe doesn't maintain it, and since it simply maps the JS API and call it via ExternalInterface, you are better off implementing FB calls in your HTML in JS and call them yourself from AS3 via ExternalInterface.
This ensures you will be using the latest JS API and not have a broken code everytime Facebook changes something.
When Facebook changes something in their API you can update your JS code rather then be left helpless hoping that Adobe would allocate resources to update the Facebook swc.
In short, using the native JS API is smoother. Good Luck!